# Get value of array in variable in vb

Tags: arrays, vb.net

ShoppingProductCard get all value when i expand it look like

[image]

In this i want to get value of all items(`Quantity,fkproductID etc`) in variable.
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not 100% sure what the problem is

```
Dim ID as Integer
ID = shoppingProductsCart(CartID).fkFrequencyAutoshipTypeID
```

is this what you wanted? (CartID in your Case would be 0)

Comment: yes i tried (CartID in your Case would be 0) now it's Working. thanks